# Search Api, solr, Facet api and facet with operators like > and <

Tags: search, views

I am using search api with solr, facet api and search api views.

I have 2 integer fields and I am looking to add facets to allow the user to filter by value, like:

```
Field 1 larger than:
>10
>50
>100

Field 2 less than:
<150
<100
<50
```

I have tried with https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_ranges but I did not have any success. Do you have any recommendations?